# Bundle file not found

Tags: javascript, express, server

Got my whole app up and working, created a new page and it cant find it

app.js:

```
app.get('/logged_in', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/logged_in.html');
});
```

webpack.config.is

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
```

now added in this to app.js:

```
app.get('/messaging', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/messaging.html');
});
```

and i get an error: `http://localhost:3000/messaging.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)`

one last thing:

in my html files I have

logged_in.html > `<script src="logged_in.bundle.js"></script>`
messaging.html > `<script src="messaging.bundle.js"></script>`

cannot work out why it wont work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which framework you use, in [express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) you should use `app.use(express.static(...))` to serve static file to client.

You can see this document to get more information:http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

---

Example:

If you put `bundle.js` in dist, and dist is under project's root directory. You want to serve `bundle.js` to client, you should set `bundle.js` or folder which contain `bundle.js` to static.

```
app.use('/static', express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`))
```

then, you can use `http://localhost:3000/static/bundle.js` to get `bundle.js` in client.